# What is the best way to fail after timeout?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm new in C# and I want to create an algorithm that will stop connect after some timeout value.

```
private void SetupConnection()
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    while (true)
    {
           try
            {
                ConnectToDataServer();
                break;
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                if (stopwatch.Elapsed < _request.TransferTimeout)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                }
                else
                {
                    _request.TransferTimeout = new TimeSpan();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it good algorithm to fail after timeout? If no how can I improve it?

Comment: This is better suited for CodeReview section because you ask for opinions and do not have a specific problem. Anyways here is my opinion: Because time is relative to the machine your code runs on I would go for a limited amount of tries before failing. For example The server gets 50 chances to respond to your client before the client accepts that the server is not responding. Also make sure that your loop does not freeze the GUI while trying over and over again. I would recommend a BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Propagates notification that operations should be canceled.

The recommended approach would be to pass it to your `ConnectToDataServer` method:

```
private void SetupConnection()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellation.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    ConnectToDataServer(cancellation.Token);
}
```

An [OperationCanceledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) will be thrown if timeout is reached.

Your `ConnectToDataServer` should keep on passing the argument, until you can handle cancellation appropiately.

If you are using a third-party library internally, the API should have a method overload accepting a `CancellationToken`.

---

#### If you can't change ConnectToDataServer method

Then your best choice is to wrap your call around a `Task`:

```
private void SetupConnection()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellation.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Task.Run(() => ConnectToDataServer(), cancellation.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```